# Looking for data on 3D Printer sales trends worldwide

Tags: data-request, economics, industry

I'm trying to find data on sales of 3D printers worldwide over the last few years. Can anyone help me? I'm basically looking for the data to include type of printer, years, sales, so that I can compare printers in the market. This is for a homework assignment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

These data are compiled in the annual Wohlers Report, which is US $495.
See https://wohlersassociates.com/2016report.htm.

There is no free source for these sales figures if you need a comprehensive dataset. I would call or email Wohler's Associates and ask if there is a research/academic edition available; it's a small company and friendly to work with.